# How to use Azure Vault Secret for the configuration provider in your function APP where the secret name has some custom pre-fix?

Tags: c#, configuration, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

Need to use Azure Keyvault as the function app configuration provider. The secret vault has a prefix "Configuration—". All the secret names which have this prefix will be added as configuration parameter for the function app.

Tried to fetch the configuration value and then match with the required prefix is there or not however there are some components which required some pre-defined configuration parameter in the config. like for SignalR it requires `AzureSignalRConnectionString` configuration name and for my case it stored as `Configuration:AzureSignalRConnectionString` in the vault. So, in that case, it fails as the required config name is not there in the configuration.

Comment: It's a **secret** - not a "secrete" .....

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Azure Secrete names have a prefix named “Configuration—“. All the secrets which have this pre-fix need to be included as environment variables. To do this – you need to follow the below steps.
Create a class in the same namespace of the startup class –

```
public class SamplePrefixKeyVaultSecretManager : KeyVaultSecretManager
{
    private readonly string _prefix;

    public SamplePrefixKeyVaultSecretManager(string prefix)
        => _prefix = $"{prefix}--";

    public override bool Load(SecretProperties properties)
        => properties.Name.StartsWith(_prefix);

    public override string GetKey(KeyVaultSecret secret)
        => secret.Name[_prefix.Length..].Replace("--", ConfigurationPath.KeyDelimiter);
}
```

Now, add the below code to add the environment variables for the function app from the Azure secrete vault whose prefix is “Configuration—“.

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        configBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri("Azure Key Vault URL"), new DefaultAzureCredential(), new SamplePrefixKeyVaultSecretManager("Configuration"));
        var config = configBuilder.Build();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config);
    }
```